# Разное количество операндов

Tags: ассемблер, intel

Почему для `imul` предусмотрено 1/2/3 операнда, а для `mul` только 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исторически. Изначально, в 8086 процессорах, и mul, и imul были только в однооперандной форме, из-за ограничений на длину опкодов. Позже, в 286, появилась возможность впихнуть больше. Выбор сделали в пользу imul. Скорее всего потому, что именно для знакового умножения может быть интересней получать более "короткий" результат, как с 2 и 3 операндами. Тогда как для беззнакового чаще всего интересуют более "длинные" произведения, в ax:dx или eax:edx (напоминаю, что однооперандная форма imul - это единственный способ получить такое "большое" частное).

Надеюсь, не запутал :)